# Custom css without preceding class

Tags: css, media-queries

How would I do the following (convert my idea into something that works)?

*(I know @media is limited to screen, all etc.)*

I want to have 1! .css file and have multiple definitions for *html* ... ->

In this example I am defining a css-rule-set (background: red) for the page and I only want it to work when I set the media tag of html. I do not want to go through all css and set a special *.special_only_this_site .classXthat_already_was_here* for each and every tag ...

```
<html media="frontpage">
 <body> ... ... </body
</html>
```

and then address it as ?

```
/* this css is only for html with media tag frontpage */
@media only frontpage {
    html {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with vanilla CSS.

But that's what [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) is for. There you could just do this:

```
.frontpage {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
  a {
    color: blue;
  }
}

<html class="frontpage">
   <body> ... ... </body
</html>
```

which compiles to:

```
.frontpage body {
  background: red;
}
.frontpage a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing/able to add a single, differant class to the html/body tag of each seperate page/site then you can just use css custom properties.

Simply create a new class and apply overwriting variables to that class. You can create as many themes as you wish and will only have to change the variables within the class at the top of your master stylesheet.

```css
/*Default Theme*/
:root {
  --colorBackground: #ffffff;
  --colorPrimary: #000;
}


/*Theme 2*/
.frontpage {
  --colorBackground: red;
  --colorPrimary: #fff;
}

body {
  background: var(--colorBackground);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: var(--colorPrimary);
}
```

```html
<body class="frontpage">
  <h1>Custom theme</h1>
</body>
```

---

### THEME SWITCHING EXAMPLE

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("frontpage");
}
```

```css
/*Default Theme*/

 :root {
  --colorBackground: #ffffff;
  --colorBackgroundOn: #53575c;
  --colorFrameAlpha: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  --colorPrimary: #16848f;
  --colorPrimaryOn: #ffffff;
  --colorSecondary: #72c253;
  --colorSecondaryOn: #ffffff;
  --fontPrimary: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  --fontSecondary: Century Gothic, CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}


/*Theme 2*/

.frontpage {
  --colorBackground: #121212;
  --colorBackgroundOn: #eeeeee;
  --colorPrimary: #bb86fc;
  --colorPrimaryOn: #121212;
  --colorSecondary: #03dac6;
  --colorSecondaryOn: #121212;
  --fontPrimary: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  --fontSecondary: Copperplate, Copperplate Gothic Light, fantasy;
}

body {
  background: var(--colorBackground);
  color: var(--colorBackgroundOn);
  font-family: var(--fontPrimary);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: var(--colorPrimary);
  font-family: var(--fontSecondary);
}

input {
  border: 3px solid var(--colorSecondary);
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: var(--colorSecondary);
  color: var(--colorSecondaryOn);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Custom theme</h1>
  <input type="text" value="example input" />
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Switch theme" />
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input ...however this would then lead me to add .frontpage to every single css rule -> .frontpage input, .frontpage input[type=checkbox]  etc...

Comment: @DavidDunham I think you are misunderstanding how custom properties work. You only need to create your variables once for each variation. You will write the class `.frontpage` only twice: Once to declare a set of variables and once to apply to the body tag.

Comment: @DavidDunham I've added an example above. All the styles will cascade through depending on which class you add to your body.